# jquery plugin using base64 image data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, base64

I am using Angular Js and getting my images from the server as Base 64 data as follows :-

```
<li ng-repeat="media in sharedMedia">
    <div class="card-groupinfo--media--wrap">
        <p>{{media.from}}</p>   <span class="media--timestamp">{{media.ts}}</span>

    </div>
    <img ng-src="{{media.d}}">
</li>
```

I wanted to now use a jquery plugin for slideshow which is as follows :-http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/

But how do i do it with the base 64 data ?

Comment: Just change your `src` to include `data:image/png;base64,` before the actual base64 value.

Comment: Doing it But throwing an error $sce of angular :: that says i am trying to get access unsecure url